# Probabilities playing bridge

Tags: probability, card-games

Being very bad with probabilities, I would greatly appreciate help for the following problem.

The first bid of my partner indicates that, among his $13$ cards, he handles $6$ hearts and a maximum of $3$ spades.

In my hand, I handle $0$ hearts and $6$ spades.

So, my question is : what are the probabilities corresponding to $0$, $1$, $2$ or $3$ spades in my partner's hand ?

Should I need to precise that this is not homework ?

Thnaks for your help.

Comment: As it is not for homework, I assume this is a real situation? If so, did you randomly shuffle the deck of cards, or do you play with prepared hands?

Comment: @Hetebrij. The deck is normally shuffled. It is a real situation and my partner and I have strong discussions about this (not uncommon) situation.

Comment: Seems appropriate to explain the rules of the game here.

Comment: As an aside, if you have questions about Bridge (although I guess this is perhaps more a question about probabilities), there is always http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/ as a good place to ask.

Comment: @SimonRose. Thanks ! I use it but the problem here was just about probabilities.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - I figured, but I thought I'd mention it just in case you hadn't seen it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 19 diamonds/clubs and 7 spades available, from which he is dealt 7 cards.

So number of ways of getting $k$ spades is ${7\choose k}{19\choose7-k}$. That gives 50388,189924,244188,135660. Hence the probabilities are 0 spades 8.125%, 1 spade 30.625%, 2 spades 39.375%, 3 spades 21.875%.

Comment: Thanks for answering ! I cannot discuss the approach but for 2 spades, you and true blue mill get something different (39.4 % and 32.2%). Who is right ? Cheers.

Comment: +1 Nice and concise. Just the numbers and taking in account the maximum of $3$ spades.

Comment: Since your answers are all multiples of $\frac{1}{160}$, there might be a way which avoids such a big multiplication

Comment: @Henry Yes I wondered that. Or it might just be cancellation amongst the factorials.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the probability will depend on the numbers of jacks, queens, kings and aces in your hand, since you know how many points your partner has.

But let's forget that extra piece of information, then your hand consists of $6$ high cards, denote that by $H$, and $7$ low cards, $L$. Then we want to find out $P(H_p = i)$ for $i =6,7,8,9$, given that you have $H_m =6$.
So we first find the number of ways to obtain $H_p =i$.
We have $6$ hearts out of a possible $13$ hearts.
We have $i-6$ spades out of a possible $7$ spades.
We have $13-i$ low cards out of a possible $19$ low cards.
So the number of combination wihich gives $H_p=i$ is
$$\binom{13}{6}\binom{7}{i-6} \binom{19}{13-i} .$$
As we know that $H_p$ lies between $6$ and $9$, we have
$$ P(H_p = i) = \frac{ \binom{13}{6} \binom{7}{i-6} \binom{19}{13-i}}{ \sum_{i=6}^9 \binom{13}{6} \binom{7}{i-6} \binom{19}{13-i}}.$$

This gives the probability on $n$ spades as $\frac{13}{160}$ for $0$, $\frac{49}{160}$ for $1$, $\frac{63}{160}$ for $2$ and $\frac{35}{160}$ for 3.
So let your partner know that you have quite a lot of spades, as in most cases you will have a fit in spades.

Comment: Thanks for answering ! Forget the values of the cards. What I am looking for is : how many cards could we have in spades in order to possibely  play something better in spades than in hearts. With this kind of hands, distribution is definetely more important than points.

Comment: This is very interesting. I shall use these for improving our bidding system (after the partner opens a weak 2 hearts or 2 spades). Thanks again.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Well, if you have a lot of points, it might be possible that your partner must have the jack, queen and ace of clubs, thus the probability will change. Likewise, if your partner must have the jack and queen of spades, you are certain of a fit in spades.